# Property set when leave page

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, data-binding

I have a `CheckBox` in a `TabControl`.
I bound the property `Checked` like this :

```
MyCheckBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", MyBindingSource, "IsOn", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Property isOn :

```
public bool IsOn
{
    get
    {
        return _isOn;
    }
    set
    {
        bool someCondition;
        // a test is done
        if (value != _isOn && someCondition)
        {
            _isOn = value;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Condition not OK");
        }
    }
}
```

When user click on the `CheckBox`, when `someCondition` is false, a message box is displayed and the `CheckBox` does not change.

My problem is when user changes page in `TabControl`, the message is displayed. I saw with debugger that when page changes in `TabControl`, property is set to the last value tried.

What can I do to not display a `MessageBox` when changing page?

Comment: It's not clear why the property would be responding to a tab change. Are you doing something in code when the user is changing tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution : forcing `Checked` property when displaying error.

```
public bool IsOn
{
    get
    {
        return _isOn;
    }
    set
    {
        bool someCondition;
        // a test is done
        if (value != _isOn && someCondition)
        {
            _isOn = value;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Condition not OK");
            MyCheckBox.Checked = !value; // here is my solution
        }
    }
}
```

But I still don't understand why I have to do this. I expect trouble due to binding.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the `SelectedIndex` of the `tabPage` before displaying the messagebox, in the example it is index 0 - change `MsgTabPage` field with the index in your app:

```
 private int MsgTabPage = 0; // the tab page that the msgbox should be displayed
 public bool IsOn
 {
     get
     {
         return _isOn;
     }
     set
     {
         bool someCondition = false;
         // a test is done
         if (value != _isOn && someCondition)
         {
             _isOn = value;
         }
         else
         {
             if(tabControl1.SelectedIndex == MsgTabPage)
             System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Condition not OK");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain, but my application use a dll to manages the pages. I don't has any access to `tabControl1.SelectedIndex`. By the way I wanted to know, why the property `Checked` of the checkbos is set to true when I change page ?

Answer (score -1):

Is it important to be able to tab over the control?

if not then you could just set the TabStop property to false
Hope this helps :)